# how to Enter data from keyboard in shell programming

Tags: bash, unix, shell

how to Enter data from keyboard in shell programming ?

some command similar to scanf in c

Comment: Please be aware that depending on your shell things maybe different. Please retag to say which shell: bash, korn, csh

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use "`read`" :

```
$ cat ./test.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "enter the value : "
read my_var

echo "The value is : $my_var"
```

And, executing the script :

```
$ sh ./test.sh
enter the value : 145
The value is : 145
```

Comment: Bash: "read" has some useful options, e.g. -p to specify a prompt:

read -p 'enter a value : '  my_var

Please see "help read" for more.

Comment: `-s` option behaves great for password entries that we don't wish to be displayed: _The -s option causes input coming from a terminal to not be echoed._

Answer (score 0):

You may use "cat"

Input can be accomplished using the cat statement.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    name=$(cat)
    echo "Welcome" "$name"
```

If we take input as Bash. Then the output :

```
Welcome Bash
```